# Grouping Parameters in Python Toolbox of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox

I am making a [Python Toolbox](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/geoprocessing_and_python/creating-a-new-python-toolbox.htm) for ArcGIS Pro. The main tool in the toolbox needs to have 5 radio buttons: Users can select any number of options (from 0 to 5).

Is it possible to group or cluster the radio buttons in a single dialog box? Further, since the parameters are optional inputs, is it possible to collapse the dialog box under a drop-down list?
[image: Toolbox Code, and ESRI-Interface]

Here is the code from the .pyt file, shown in the screenshot above:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import arcpy

class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "PDF Toolbox"
        self.alias = "Toolbox of PDFs"
        self.tools = [GhostScriptCompress]

class GhostScriptCompress(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = "Ghostscript PDF Compression Tool"
        self.description = "Compresses large PDFs using Ghostscript"
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions."""
        inPDF = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Input PDF Document",
                                name="outCompiledName",
                                datatype="DEFile",
                                parameterType="Required",
                                direction="Input")
                
        screen = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Ghostscript 'screen' Compression",
                                 name="gsCompress_screen",
                                 datatype="GPBoolean",
                                 parameterType="Optional",
                                 direction="Input")
        ebook = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Ghostscript 'ebook' Compression",
                                name="gsCompress_ebook",
                                datatype="GPBoolean",
                                parameterType="Optional",
                                direction="Input")
        printer = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Ghostscript 'printer' Compression",
                                  name="gsCompress_printer",
                                  datatype="GPBoolean",
                                  parameterType="Optional",
                                  direction="Input")
        prepress = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Ghostscript 'prepress' Compression",
                                   name="gsCompress_prepress",
                                   datatype="GPBoolean",
                                   parameterType="Optional",
                                   direction="Input")
        default = arcpy.Parameter(displayName="Ghostscript 'default' Compression",
                                  name="gsCompress_default",
                                  datatype="GPBoolean",
                                  parameterType="Optional",
                                  direction="Input")
        
        params = [inPDF, screen, ebook, printer, prepress, default]
        return params

    def isLicensed(self):
        """Set whether tool is licensed to execute."""
        return True
    def updateParameters(self, parameters):
        """Modify the values and properties of parameters before internal validation 
        is performed.  This method is called whenever a parameter has been changed."""
        return
    def updateMessages(self, parameters):
        """Modify the messages created by internal validation for each tool
        parameter.  This method is called after internal validation."""
        return
    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
        """The source code of the tool."""
        for param in parameters:
            arcpy.AddMessage(f"Parameter ValueAsText: {param.valueAsText}")
            arcpy.AddMessage(f"Parameter Value: {param.value}")
            arcpy.AddMessage(f"Parameter Type: {type(param)}")
            arcpy.AddMessage("-----------------------")
        return
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a category to the parameters that you want to group.
For example

```
screen = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Ghostscript 'screen' Compression",
    name="gsCompress_screen",
    datatype="GPBoolean",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input",
    category="Compression",
)
ebook = arcpy.Parameter(
    displayName="Ghostscript 'ebook' Compression",
    name="gsCompress_ebook",
    datatype="GPBoolean",
    parameterType="Optional",
    direction="Input",
    category="Compression",
)
```

Comment: Thanks, @MarkBryant, it was right there in the documentation... https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/parameter.htm#P_GUID-4454F8E8-6EE2-4AC1-A8E0-3C97660FF457  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I used [@Mark Bryant's "category" answer/suggestion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/400961/115), coupled with using a "multiValue" parameter-type, instead of a bunch of individual parameter types. Screenshot shows the updated .pyt file, and two ArcGIS Pro views of the tool in the Geoprocessing pane: One collapsed, one expanded.

[image]